# Add character to end of layer names of rasterStack in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a rasterstack with 19 layers for each year from 2006 to 2100 (e.g., 2006.1...2006.19, 2007.1...2007.19, and so forth):

```
class      : RasterStack
dimensions : 3875, 8017, 31065875, 1786  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.04490319, 0.04490319  (x, y)
extent     : -180.0393, 179.9495, -90.04088, 83.95898  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
names      : biovars2006.1, biovars2006.2, biovars2006.3, biovars2006.4, biovars2006.5, biovars2006.6, biovars2006.7, biovars2006.8, biovars2006.9, biovars2006.10, biovars2006.11, biovars2006.12, biovars2006.13, biovars2006.14, biovars2006.15, ...
min values : 220.864166260,   0.389879853,   4.384806633,   9.609144211, 242.441360474, 206.977874756,   1.603729248, 212.457183838, 214.414901733,  237.330688477,  209.619567871,    0.000000000,    0.000000000,    0.000000000,    0.000000000, ...
max values :  3.071921e+02,  1.719736e+01,  8.752898e+01,  2.353919e+03,  3.234787e+02,  3.004958e+02,  7.261229e+01,  3.116087e+02,  3.133256e+02,   3.134417e+02,   3.027429e+02,   4.340919e-03,   1.964979e-03,   2.542563e-04,   5.758981e-02, ...
```

I want to extract only layer 1 for each year as follows:

```
future.Rast.bio1 <- raster::subset(future.Rast, grep(".1", names(future.Rast), value = T))
```

But of course that gives me values for .1, .10, .11 ... and so forth. I thought one way to get around this could be to add an underscore after the .number in the layers. How can I do this, or does anyone have another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a little test set (maybe expand this to a few more examples):

```
> nms = c("2000.1","2000.11","2000.01","2000.21","2000.12")
```

You want those that have a dot, a 1 and then the end of the string. To match a dot you have to "escape" the dot in the grep string (otherwise a dot matches any single character) and to match the end of the string you use a dollar-sign. So:

```
> grep("\\.1$", nms, value = T)
[1] "2000.1"
```

looks like it gets you what you want...